# Find out if Web page and desktop application are launched on the same computer

Tags: javascript, .net, desktop

I have a desktop application (little service in the system tray) and some web application. In case a user loads the web page I need to be able to find out that both the web page and the desktop application are running on the same computer.

On the desktop application I could easily get access to hard disk serial number, ethernet mac address, etc. and identify computer based on this information. But I don't have access to it in JavaScript on the web page.

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

**Update.** A little bit more information about why I need that. I'm working on a medical software. The idea is that when a user loads the web page, he can press Import button and make the import from medical device that is attached to his computer (the import itself is done by a tray-application on the user's computer)

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to use something like an external application request from the webpage?  Sort of like the thing that Spotify uses to launch the desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: it's possible, but the best way to do this would be to develop a browser extension.

Without an extension:

- You could correlate IP addresses, this wouldn't work well on Internet sites
- If it's Internet Explorer, your tray application could add a cookie to the user's cookie-jar which IE would use as well
- Other than those two options, it isn't really a way, think about how aggressively browsers defend user privacy.